# How to check order exist or not in commerce order?

Tags: commerce, hooks, 7

I am using Drupal 7.31 and the [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution. I added an order using CSV file in commerce_payment_transaction table.

I want to check the condition below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");    

  $i = 1;
  $f_status = FALSE;
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      if($i > 2){

        $o_id = $data[1]; // I am fetch order_id from csv. I wont to check which order_id is coming from csv is present on commerce_order or not?                   
        $remote_id = $data[2];
        $created = strtotime($data[7]);
        $changed = strtotime($data[11]);
        $amount = $data[8] * 100;

        $db_query = db_select('commerce_payment_transaction','cpt');
        $db_query->fields('cpt');
        $db_query->condition('cpt.order_id',$o_id,'=');
        $db_res = $db_query->execute();
        $row_count = $db_res->rowCount();

        if($row_count == 0){
            $o_load = commerce_order_load($o_id);
        }
    }
  }
}else{
   $output = "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";
   $output .= "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>";
   $output .= "File name to import:<br />\n";
   $output .= "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
   $output .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload CSV'></form>";
   return $output;
 }
 $i++;
}
```

How can I do so?

Comment: what is the relation between  order_id exists(valid) and ` I added an order using CSV file in commerce_payment_transaction table.` ?

Comment: On a sidenote, you are aware that lots of security updates have been released since Drupal 7.31, including [SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005)?

Comment: @zhilevan I added code just check it once.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this using `commerce_order_load()`

```
if(commerce_order_load($order_id)){
    //Do something
}
else{
   //Do something
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: this condition not working

Comment: @priyank, it should. If an order is found, [commerce_order_load](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_load/7) returns the object, if not object was found it returns FALSE.